# How to change the SCNCamera rotation according to looksAt and up-vector?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, scenekit

Given are the vector of direction in which the `SCNCamera` looks and the up vector that points into the upside direction of the camera.

How can the rotation of the camera of each individual axis be calculated?

Comment: The following question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635947/what-exactly-is-the-up-vector-in-opengls-lookat-function